# Taking photo in C++/CX with Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, c++-cx

I am working in C++/CX (in Visual Studio 2013) on an app for Windows phone 8.1 systems. I test my app on a Nokia Lumia 930. My app must take photos to do some image processing on them. Therefore I would like to have a `byte*` or `char*` or `unsigned char*` to to whatever I want. So I tried to use `::Windows::Media::Capture::MediaCapture::CapturePhotoToStreamAsync` to get the content of the photo into a stream and then with a `::Windows::Storage::Streams::DataReader` get the actual bytes of the photo. But I have been unsuccessful. More precisely the problem is here in the code that follows.

```
IRandomAccessStream ^ras = ref new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();
IAsyncAction ^ac = cap->CapturePhotoToStreamAsync(ImageEncodingProperties::CreateBmp(),ras);
ac->Completed = ref new AsyncActionCompletedHandler(
[=] (IAsyncAction ^async_op,AsyncStatus status) mutable
{
    debug->Text = L"finished";
});
```

where `cap` is a managed pointer to a MediaCapture which seems to be correctly initialized.

But the `debug` TextBlock never shows `finished`. And when I get the status of `ac` it seems to be blocked on `Started` forever, it never gets to `Error` or `Completed`. I do not understand why. So for now I implemented a dirty workaround that uses `::Windows::Media::Capture::MediaCapture::CapturePhotoToStorageFileAsync`. But storing the photo in a bitmap on a file then reading it back to get the image back in memory is not satisfactory at all.

I have found a lot on taking photos with Windows Phone 8.1, but they are all in C# and copy-pasting those solutions by replacing the `'.'` by `'::'` does not work. I mean it is (at least for me) not easy at all to adapt C# code to C++ code.

So my questions are :

1. Is there a quick and/or clean way of getting a good old C pointer to the pixels of the image?
2. Why do `CapturePhotoToStreamAsync` block with status `Started`?

Thank you for your answers and your time.

Comment: Not "whatever"; tag your question properly

Comment: Ok it is now tagged correctly.

Comment: This is not C++/CLI, the language extension is called C++/CX.  It is pure native code.  Use the [sample code](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Media-Capture-Sample-adf87622).

Comment: Ok excuses, I change CLI to Cx

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the basic camera sample app on the Microsoft Github page: https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/CameraStarterKit

There's a lot you need to do before you can take a picture (initialize, configure, start preview, etc.) and the sample will walk you through it.

Here's a shortened snippet from the sample I linked above:

```
/// <summary>
/// Takes a photo to a StorageFile and adds rotation metadata to it
/// </summary>
/// <returns></returns>
task<void> MainPage::TakePhotoAsync()
{   
    auto inputStream = ref new Streams::InMemoryRandomAccessStream();

    // Take the picture
    WriteLine("Taking photo...");
    return create_task(_mediaCapture->CapturePhotoToStreamAsync(Windows::Media::MediaProperties::ImageEncodingProperties::CreateJpeg(), inputStream))
        .then([this, inputStream]()
    {
        WriteLine("Photo taken!");

        auto photoOrientation = ConvertOrientationToPhotoOrientation(GetCameraOrientation());
        return ReencodeAndSavePhotoAsync(inputStream, photoOrientation);
    }).then([this](task<void> previousTask)
    {
        try
        {
            previousTask.get();
        }
        catch (Exception^ ex)
        {
            WriteException(ex);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Hi, I just tried your solution but it does not work for me. I have the behavior I described in my question. `CapturePhotoToStreamAsync` seems to be blocked with `Status == Started`. It never goes to `Error` or `Completed` and therefore the created task never finishes. I think I do all what is needed before taking the picture because when I use `CapturePhotoToStorageFileAsync` instead of `CapturePhotoToStreamAsync` all is working fine. Have you any idea why `CapturePhotoToStreamAsync` is blocking like that whereas `CapturePhotoToStorageFileAsync` is working ? Thanks

Comment: Change your `ImageEncodingProperties::CreateBmp()` to `ImageEncodingProperties::CreateJpeg()`, like my snippet does.